# Unable to query a db from gradle build script

Tags: sql-server, gradle, groovy, jtds

I am trying to query a db from within a gradle script task. I started with a groovy script to verify the code

```
import groovy.sql.Sql

this.class.classLoader.rootLoader.addURL(new URL('file:<..>/jtds-1.2.2.jar'))
def driver = 'net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver'
def dburl = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://ITSVIL:1433/APPDB"
def first
Sql.withInstance(dburl, '<..>', '<..>', driver) {
    sql ->
        first = sql.firstRow( "SELECT * FROM PROJECT" )
}
```

I launched with groovy QueryTest.groovy and verified that it worked. Then I moved the script within a gradle task, no changes on code but loading handled by gradle buildscript statement

```
import groovy.sql.Sql

defaultTasks 'queryTest'

buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath files('<..>/jtds-1.2.2.jar')
    }
}

task queryTest () {

    // l'update va su REPOSITORYURL + '/' + alm.project.vcrProjectName + '/' + Reference

    doLast {

        def driver = 'net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver'
        def dburl = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://ITSVIL:1433/APPDB"
        def first
        Sql.withInstance(dburl, '<..>', '<..>', driver) {
            sql ->
                first = sql.firstRow( "SELECT * FROM PROJECT" )
        }
    }
}
```

Launched with gradle -b QueryTest.gradle, this time I am getting

```
Execution failed for task ':queryTest'.
> java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://ITSVIL:1433/IKALM_APP
```

Tried any possible advice I found in forums without success. Would ask for help.

Comment: The reason I am using a local jar is that no access to maven or jcenter is possible from that machine

Answer (score 5):

Due to groovy dynamic nature, classloading within gradle is quite complex. I would like to thank @cptwonton that pointed me to a great explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44740416/drivermanager-doesnt-see-dependency-in-gradle-custom-plugins-task)

I had to modify the gradle script a little and this is the working version. The jdts-1.2.2.jar is in the lib directory referred by flatDir.

```
import groovy.sql.Sql

defaultTasks 'queryTest'

task queryTest () {
    repositories {
        flatDir {
            dirs 'lib'
        }
    }
    configurations {
        jdbc
    }
    dependencies {
        jdbc 'net.sourceforge.jtds:jtds:1.2.2'
    }

    doLast {
        def sqlClassLoader = Sql.classLoader
        configurations.jdbc.each { sqlClassLoader.addURL it.toURI().toURL() }

        def driver = 'net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver'
        def dburl = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://ITSVIL:1433/APPDB"
        def first
        Sql.withInstance(dburl, '<..>', '<..>', driver) {
            sql ->
                first = sql.firstRow( "SELECT * FROM PROJECT" )
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your `net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver` is not available.
This is likely because of an issue with your path in

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath files('..../jtds-1.2.2.jar')
    }
}
```

The **path** you provide to classpath files( **path** ) needs to be a relative path to the root of your gradle project directory. I'd suggest moving your jtds jar into the libs directory, and taking a look at this doc:
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sub:file_dependencies

Also, the jtds jar is on the maven repo, why not use that instead of a local jar? The beauty of build tools like gradle and maven is that you do not need to locally store or manage many popular jars.

Comment: Both the groovy code and the gradle code refer the same jar file.  I omitted the whole path and put some periods. Sorry that was not clear. I try to edit and make it clear.

Comment: I see.
Have you see the docs referenced here?
http://jtds.sourceforge.net/faq.html#noSuitableDriver
You may need to register jTDS with the DriverManager first with Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver")
try playing around with that and see if it gets you anywhere

Also take a look at this other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44740416/drivermanager-doesnt-see-dependency-in-gradle-custom-plugins-task

Comment: The reason I am using local jar is that no access to maven or jcenter is possible from that machine.

Comment: Tried also Class.forName but the error message does not change: "java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver" etc etc

Comment: The "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver" error message is thrown by classloader. That's what the buildscript dependencies classpath files code is for.
But that is quite different from Java's DriverManager not knowing where to find the driver - which is most certainly your issue at hand.

Comment: Sorry I was unable to get you completely to the answer. You may find better luck on the jTDS forums :)